# ZendAMF 1.11 and the missing source

Tags: arraycollection, zend-amf

We are trying to upgrade from an older version of Zend Framework to the most recent one (1.11).

We have to send some ArrayCollections to a Flex-app that I can not access. Previous versions of ZF's `Zend_Amf_Value_Messaging_ArrayCollection` have a `source` attribute which the newer versions don't have.

I have tried editing the `Zend_Amf_Value_Messaging_ArrayCollection` class to have that `source` property, but it seems like ZF doesn't send objects to the Flex-app (I've noticed that via a debugging proxy). The ArrayCollection still has the correct keys (AFAIK, going from 0 -> 3), but the values are `NULL`.

This is from a small test-file:

```
$c = new RoomCategoryVO();
$c->name = 'root';
$c->childCategories = new Zend_Amf_Value_Messaging_ArrayCollection();

$cc1 = new RoomCategoryVO();
$cc1->sortPriority = 2;
$cc1->name = $this->xml->roomService->windows;
$cc1->parentCategory = $c;
$cc1->childItems = new Zend_Amf_Value_Messaging_ArrayCollection();
$re11 = new ElementVO();
$re11->id = "simpleWindow";
$re11->name = $this->xml->roomService->window;
$re11->type = 'SIMPLE_WINDOW';
$re11->icon = 'assets/runtime/images/schemeIcons/simpleWindow.png';
//$cc1->childItems->source[] = $re11;
$cc1->childItems[] = $re11;


//$c->childCategories->source[] = $cc1;
$c->childCategories->append($cc1);
```

In comments you see the 'old' way of ZendAMF, below them the new way.

Is there any way to get ZendAMF use the `source` property again without going back to an older version of ZF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally settled on using ZendAMF, with only the `Zend_Amf_Value_Messaging_ArrayCollection` from the previous version being:

```
class Zend_Amf_Value_Messaging_ArrayCollection
{
    public $source;
}
```

This allows us still using the `source` property.